# How to parse a single csv file column in multiple n sized arrays?

Tags: python, csv

**Assumptions:**

1. We are dealing with properly formatted csv file.
2. The csv file contains a single column (so there are no `,` in the file just `\n`'s)
3. There are a variable amount of rows

**My Question:** Consider the below portion of code.

```
import csv
def ReadCsv(pathname, chunkSize):
    with open(pathname) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        row_count = sum(1 for row in reader)
        columnChucks = [] # This will be a 2 dim array of
                          # which will contains a list of
                          # chunkSize arrays that contian
                          # the data cells of that block
```

What is the **best** way to split the first (and only in this case) column of the csv file into a List that contains a list of `chuckSized` data cells?

Note 1: If the `chunkSize` is 7 and the csv file has 8 cells, then the last cell should just be ignored.
Note 2: The case where `chunkSize` is greater than the cells in the csv file will be ignored.

**Example**

*Input*

chunkSize = 2

csv file =

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

*Result*

`print(columnChunks)` should be equivalent to

```
[ [1,2]
  [3,4]
  [5,6] ]
```

Comment: What if there were 7 entries and you decided to use chunks of 2, how would that look like, per your use case?

Comment: Check `Note 1` in my answer

Comment: I need clarity, should I ignore if chunksize is not a factor of length of the document?

Comment: You should just throw away the cells that make the csv not a factor of chunk size

Comment: Find my answer below, truncate the sequence as necessary and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your chunksize is going to be a factor of the length of the document, the following example may solve your problem.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]) #replace with the readcsv output
chunksize = 2
ll = len(df[0])
result = df.transpose().values.reshape(ll//chunksize,chunksize)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close!  You don't need csv reader or Pandas for just reading a csv (note this will conveniently omit any remainder < chunk_size:

```
In [21]: result = []                                                           

In [22]: count = 0                                                             

In [23]: chunk_size = 2                                                        

In [24]: element = []                                                          

In [25]: with open('data.csv','r') as f: 
    ...:     for line in f: 
    ...:         element.append(line.strip()) 
    ...:         if count == chunk_size-1: 
    ...:             result.append(element) 
    ...:             # reset count 
    ...:             element = [] 
    ...:             count = 0 
    ...:         else: 
    ...:             count += 1 
    ...:              
    ...:              
    ...:              
    ...:                                                                       

In [26]: result                                                                
Out[26]: [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['4', '5'], ['6', '7'], ['8', '9']]
```

Comment: pandas would speed up the process though, through vectorization.

Comment: not likely.  there is no vectorization of "reading" to my knowledge.  Python can read galactic sized .csv files in a flash

Comment: exactly, with your code, you are forcing it into doing I/O and processing in an intertwined fashion. Let it read the whole file first and then process it in a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that might work:

```py
def make_array(file, chunksize):
    outerlist = []
    with open(file, 'r') as fp:
        EOF = False
        while not EOF:
            innerlist = []
            for _ in range(chunksize):
               item = fp.readline().strip('\n')
               if not item:
                   EOF = True
               innerlist.append(item)
            outerlist.append(innerlist)
    return outerlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your note #1 and adapting @SANTOSH KUMAR DESAI's answer,

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) #replace with the readcsv output
chunksize = 2
ll = len(df[0])
mod = ll%chunksize
if(mod!=0):
    df = df[:ll-mod]
result = df.transpose().values.reshape(ll//chunksize,chunksize)
print(result)
```

This discards any extra values. Also, just as a note, I would recommend using pandas to read your csv instead of importing another csv, something like this.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = "name")
```

Overall, something like this might work.

```
import pandas
def ReadCsv(pathname, chunkSize):
    file = df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = "name_of_file")
    ll = len(df[0])
    mod = ll%chunkSize
    if(mod!=0):
        df = df[:ll-mod]
    result = df.transpose().values.reshape(ll//chunkSize,chunkSize)
    return result
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it like this which uses something *similar* to the [Itertools Recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) with the same name:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint


def grouper(iterable, n):
    """ Collect data in iterable into fixed-length chunks or blocks. """
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip(*args)


def ReadCsv(pathname, chunkSize):
    with open(pathname) as file:
        cols = (row[0] for row in csv.reader(file))
        return [list(group) for group in grouper(cols, chunkSize)]


columnChucks = ReadCsv('grouper_test.csv', 2)
pprint(columnChucks)  # -> [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
columnChucks = ReadCsv('grouper_text2.csv', 7)
pprint(columnChucks)  # -> [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']]
```